# String matching of 2 columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to compare 2 columns in BQ?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(geo, countries) THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
  END AS geo_match
FROM
  T1
LEFT JOIN
  T2
ON
  T1.id = T2.id
```

And got the following error:

```
No matching signature for function REGEXP_CONTAINS for argument types: STRING, ARRAY<STRING>. Supported signatures: REGEXP_CONTAINS(STRING, STRING); REGEXP_CONTAINS(BYTES, BYTES) at [4:10]
```

I also tried `LIKE` function. Never worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Based on error message I assume that `geo` is a string and `countries` is a repeated string (array):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  T1.id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(countries) AS country WHERE geo = country) > 0 AS geo_match
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
ORDER BY id
```

Based on your requirements you can use any comparison logic (`LIKE`, `REGEXP_CONTAINS`, etc.) instead of simple

```sql
WHERE geo = country
```

You can play/test with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'US' AS geo UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'UK' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'MX' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'CA'
), 
T2 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ['US', 'UK'] AS countries UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['MX', 'CA'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['MX', 'CA']
)
SELECT
  T1.id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(countries) AS country WHERE geo = country) > 0 AS geo_match
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!